# How to demonstrate my SASS skill?

Tags: css, sass

I have just self taught SASS by studying the SASS documentation: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html. What practical work can I do now that can best demonstrate my SASS skill and experience to employers?

I am looking for a front-end or a web developer role around 70-80K. My current skill set is HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap, JavaScript, jQuery, PHP, MySQL, WordPress, React, Angular, SVN and Photoshop. Thank you. :)

Comment: if all you've done is read the docs, you don't know sass.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a careers site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think if you understand the basics listed in the Sass website you are pretty much ready to go :)

http://sass-lang.com/guide

To demonstrate your knowledge do some demos or websites using Sass and show the code to an employer.